# Quartz job scheduler in .net core on 12AM and 12PM everyday

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduler, quartz.net

In a .NET Core 5 Web API project I have a job scheduler, which is updating something in the database.

I want to run that job scheduler twice a day at 12 AM and 12 PM. What will be the cron expression for that?

How am I able to run the Quartz job scheduler twice in a day?

Here is the code of scheduler start:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(cancellationToken);
    Scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;
           
    var job2 = new JobSchedule(jobType: typeof(MCBJob),
                cronExpression: "0 0 0/12 * * ");

    var mcbJob = CreateJob(job2);
    var mcbTrigger = CreateTrigger(job2);
             
    await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(mcbJob, mcbTrigger, cancellationToken);

    await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Try using `0 0 0,12 * *`. Use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0,12_*_*_*) to build a cron schedule.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate values with `,` to specify individual values.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression

```
4   -> 4
0-4 -> 0,1,2,3,4
*/4 -> 0,4,8,12,...,52,56
0,4 -> 0,4
```

We can build the schedule now:

```
0 0 0,12 * *
| |  |   | every month
| |  |   every day
| |  at hour 0 and 12
| at minute 0
at first second
```

You can use https://crontab.guru/ to build a cron expression interactively.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is helpful in your case.

Visit http://www.cronmaker.com/

**CronMaker** is a simple website which helps you to build **cron expressions**. **CronMaker** uses **Quartz** open source **scheduler**. Generated expressions are based on **Quartz** cron format.